# How to get a particular string from text (string) using Groovy/Java?

Tags: groovy

I am reading a mail "body" from Gmail inbox, I am receiving below text body as string but I need special string(AccountId=13234) out of the whole text body? How can we achieved using Groovy ?

Here is the details below

User: ABC
AccountId=13234
CompanyName=xyz

Thanks
Team

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What result did you get?

Comment: "is there any other way to do?" - There are really dozens of ways to do it.  Is there a particular concern that you are trying to address?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you pasted in your comment to make it more complete, and delete your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are many ways to do this.  Without more info about your specific requirements, it's not possible to know which is best.

A simple solution is:

```
def result = (s =~ "AccountId=[0-9]+")[0]
```

This will work if your content is guaranteed to always be `AccountId=` followed by some number of digits.

Comment: Great..Thanks, its suitable for my requirement